# Message Catalog Matlab:interpreter was not loaded

Tags: matlab, error-handling, ram

I have got a very strange error in MATLAB and it doesn't seem to be directly related to my program. MATLAB doesn't even give me a line where the error occurred.

My program processes a lot of files. I can process groups of them without getting an error, but when process them all of them together I get the following error:

```
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
Message Catalog MATLAB:interpreter was not loaded from the file. Please check file location, format or contents
```

This usually happens at approximately the same point, but not exactly. I tested all the files around this point and they work. This is why I assume it is related to the RAM.

If I try to run the program again I get the same error right at the beginning, but after restarting MATLAB everything runs fine again.

I was wondering if it was a C++ based error, since it contains 'std::...'

Do you have any idea what this error means and how I can fix it?

Comment: I've had a "Matlab:services was not loaded" error - leaked file handle as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like an installation problem. MATLAB is looking for a file in your installation called `$MATLABROOT/resources/MATLAB/en/interpreter.xml`. Check that file exists - you might need to re-install.

EDIT: turns out the problem was the OP's code was leaking file handles, meaning that MATLAB was eventually unable to open the resource file.

Comment: This file does exist and if it were an installation related problem it would accrue regularly, but not randomly.

Comment: Point taken - there's clearly something bad going on on your system. That error is definitely related to that file being inaccessible though, and you're quite right that 'std::exception' is being thrown from internal C++ code which is not really expecting to handle the missing file. Have you run stuff like `memtest` on your system?

Comment: It seems like this isn't the problem ether. Memtest didn't find any errors. It it possible that after running my program for a while the ram is full of fragmented allocations and Matlab isn't abled to find a continuous peace of the required size?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Perhaps MATLAB has run out of file handles or some other OS resource and cannot open the interpreter.xml file. Are you sure you're closing all those files you're processing?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I met this error today, but my reason is simple, I forgot to call fclose every time I wrote to a new file. After I add the fclose then the error has gone.

Comment: Same here, except it was MATLAB:bang instead of MATLAB:interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use fopen to open a file without fclose in the end, you will meet this problem. So solution is simple, go to fclose the file!